# C# : Marching Cubes to get Isolines and Isobands

Tags: c#, lines, cubes

Sorry for my english.

I have a set of points in 3D : P0, P1, P2, ... Subsets of this set defines Polygones in 3D.
Each point (defined before) have a temperature.

Drawing the polygones is easy.
Now, I want to draw on my polygones the isolines and isobands using temperatures (as described before).

How can I achieve this ?

I looked for the marching cubes algorithm but I don't understand how to apply it. Here is a link of the class implementing the [Marching Cubes algorithm](https://github.com/thejasonfisher/marchingCubes/blob/master/MarchingCubes.cs)

Can you help me ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can your confirm my assumption - P0 has both x, y value, since you said it is Point? Is there a separate data structure which stores the Temperatures for the Points?

Comment: P0 has x, y and z value. It's a point in 3D.

Comment: Yes, temperatures are stored separatly. I have Point3D[] polygones; and double[] temperatures; The two array have the same length.

Comment: Marching Cubes is for 3D data on a regular lattice, e.g. a 3D image of pixels (actually voxels). It does not seem that your data has that structure just as a 2D image only is represented by an array of pixel values. You do not have a separate array of pixel coordinates as they are implied.

Comment: Too bad :( I thought it works in continuous.
And do you know how I can achieve what I want with another algorithm ?